# Remove phone from billing/shipping fields everywhere in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, account

I don't need to collect customer phone numbers in woocommerce so I've used the following code to remove them from the checkout process:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'pbj_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
function pbj_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
  unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_phone']);
$fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-wide');
return $fields;}
```

(sorry for hideous code pasting, first time!)

That works great on the checkout page but once in the "my account" area, the user is still required to add a phone number if they edit their billing or shipping address. I have added this code:

```
function pbj_remove_billingphone($fields) {
unset( $fields ['billing_phone'] );
return $fields;}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'pbj_remove_billingphone' );
```

which has removed it from billing, but I can't get anything to work to remove it from shipping. Any help on either something that universally removes the phone number requirement everywhere, or tips on what to filter/unset to remove the shipping phone number on the account page? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the complete way to do it in account and checkout pages *(for **both** pages)*:

```
// Remove billing phone (and set email field class to wide)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'remove_billing_phone_field', 20, 1 );
function remove_billing_phone_field($fields) {
    $fields ['billing_phone']['required'] = false; // To be sure "NOT required"

    $fields['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-wide'); // Make the field wide

    unset( $fields ['billing_phone'] ); // Remove billing phone field
    return $fields;
}

// Remove shipping phone (optional)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'remove_shipping_phone_field', 20, 1 );
function remove_shipping_phone_field($fields) {
    $fields ['shipping_phone']['required'] = false; // To be sure "NOT required"

    unset( $fields ['shipping_phone'] ); // Remove shipping phone field
    return $fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

> Normally shipping email and phone fields doesn't exist by default in WooCommmerce

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked beautifully and I've learned a lot by comparing what I've had to your solution. I'm not sure what was adding the phone field but your solution has made my life much easier. Thanks again!

Comment: this just removed the phone number label not the actual text input .woo 3.5

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the title of the post is "Remove phone from billing/shipping fields everywhere in Woocommerce?" so yes it is about removing the phone number from checkout...... it did not work it removed the label not input box.. therefore voted down as not working.